# Layering Images & Click to Choose Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

So I'm making a gallery of fabrics and backgrounds for letters for a fraternity/sorority store in my college's town. If you don't know what I'm talking about, [this is a fabric letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn4oQ.jpg). You can see how it has a white outline (background) and a red inside (foreground). WELL, I want to make it so you can change both the foreground and background, simply by clicking it's similar image.

This is what I have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function changeImage(filename)
{
document.mainimage.src = filename;
}// ]]></script>
```

with these for each fabrics:

```
<a href="javascript:changeImage('/wp-content/themes/collegiateconnectionbg/images/fabrics/foregrounds/37.jpg')">
<img src="/wp-content/themes/collegiateconnectionbg/images/fabrics/foregrounds/37.jpg"
alt="" width="100px" height="50px" /></a>
```

I really like how this works, but it's only good for one layer. Is there anyway I can add a layer below it, but still make it show at the top of the page? I know I'll have to use photoshop and transparency for both options, thats no problem, but I wanted to make sure I can do this before I start creating 600+ images.

I know I can play with z-index and css, but since I'm using wordpress the one example I read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488390/can-you-layer-pictures-on-top-of-each-other-on-a-webpage) wasn't working or I didn't completely understand it, and messed up my entire page.

Also [here's](http://www.collegiateconnectionbg.com/customize-your-apparel/sewn-on-letters/) my tester webpage to see the current code in work. (if you click the navy&white stars image, you can see a very rough makeshift "A")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @meal - not sure what you mean by "only good for one layer". Could you photoshop something together that would show what your resulting image would look like?

Comment: @BrandonBoone Sure, [this was a very quick sketch](http://i.imgur.com/gzFym.jpg). Basically you can change the main image area, both foreground and background by clicking the appropriate swatch underneath.  What I have now could be great for just one layer (foreground) but I would also like to be able to change the background as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got a solution for you.

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hM6dj/4/

More or less, you just need to create some images of the letters and leave their insides transparent.

### Example

[image]

You'll notice that the area around the 'A' is white while the area within the lines of the 'A' is transparent.

### Code

Then all you need to do is place this image in front of another image. The image in the background will bleed through the transparent image on top resulting in an 'A' with a pattern.

*NOTE: I used data urls for the foreground letter so I wouldn't have to host the images anywhere. You can read about that [here](http://dataurl.net/#about).*

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='foreground foreground-Black'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class='background background-Cow'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<h2>Foreground Options</h2>
<input type='button' class='btnforeground' data-class='foreground-Black' value="Black" />
<input type='button' class='btnforeground' data-class='foreground-Red' value="Red" />
<input type='button' class='btnforeground' data-class='foreground-Green' value="Green" />

<h2>Background Options</h2>
<input type='button' class='btnbackground' data-class='background-Cow' value="Cow" />
<input type='button' class='btnbackground' data-class='background-Stars' value="Stars" />
<input type='button' class='btnbackground' data-class='background-Dots' value="Dots" />
​
```

**JS**

```
$('input[type="button"].btnforeground').click(function(){
    $('div.container > div.foreground').removeClass().addClass('foreground').addClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
});


$('input[type="button"].btnbackground').click(function(){
    $('div.container > div.background').removeClass().addClass('background').addClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
});
​
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    position:relative; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;    
}

.foreground, .background{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}

.background{
    background-repeat:repeat;       
    z-index:50;
}

.background-Cow{
background-image: 
url(http://www.collegiateconnectionbg.com/wp-content/themes/collegiateconnectionbg/images/fabrics/foregrounds/424.jpg);
}

.background-Stars{
background-image: 
url(http://www.collegiateconnectionbg.com/wp-content/themes/collegiateconnectionbg/images/fabrics/foregrounds/48.jpg);
}

.background-Dots{
background-image: 
url(http://www.collegiateconnectionbg.com/wp-content/themes/collegiateconnectionbg/images/fabrics/foregrounds/521.jpg);
}
/* Omitted due to StackOverflow character restrictions.
.foreground-Black{

    background-image: url();
}

.foreground-Green{
    background-image: url();
}

.foreground-Red{
    background-image: url();
}
*/
```

​

## EDIT

Using [Google Chrome's Developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview), it looks like you have some HTML intermixed with your JavaScript (notice the Paragraph Tags `<p>`, `</p>`).

[image]

Also I would wrap the jQuery events in a ready function (The JS Fiddle did this automatically so it wasn't obvious from the code example).

### JS

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="button"].btnforeground').click(function(){
        $('div.container > div.foreground').removeClass().addClass('foreground').addClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
    });


    $('input[type="button"].btnbackground').click(function(){
        $('div.container > div.background').removeClass().addClass('background').addClass($(this).attr('data-class'));
    });
});
​
```

### EDIT2

[image]

A few things.

1. Your classes:

   - .foreground
   - .background
   - .foreground-Black
   - .foreground-Cow
   - etc...

have almost none of the properties set from my example. You should be able to take the css verbatim from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hM6dj/4/) I provided.

2. You've named the container the class `.viewer`, but are referencing `.container` in your JavaScript. These elements must match for the JavaScript to be able to find the appropriate html element to update.

Comment: I love you! This is fantastic. If you have a donation link I'd love to donate to you.

I did run into some problems. I copied the cope exactly, and I put up on [here](http://www.collegiateconnectionbg.com/fabrics-test/) but the viewer part the code isn't reading! It's very sad. Any ideas of what it could be?

Only thing I changed was the .container to .viewer (I thought that may of been the problem, since I already have a container div) but that wasn't the case either.

Comment: @rneal - You're most welcome! No donation page, but [clicking the accept button for this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is just as good. See my edit. Let me know if it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of the extra `<p>`s and it's not giving me any more errors on chromes developer tool, but still no luck.

Comment: I figured it out! It turns out there were some weird artifacts from copying the code straight from jfiddle. Some weird swedish A's that didn't show up in my file, but showed up when i looked at the .css file in a browser. This made the code not show up, even though I saw it in my file. So yes, this is fantastic!

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to figure it out.