# Image Slider Effect! Scroll on Top of Each Other

Tags: jquery, html, css

Quick question does any one know any ideas how i would go about creating this effect where the images slide over the top of each.. Just need some pointers to start me off havent really got a clue where to start..

http://denicler.eu/en/lookbooks/1

manged to stack my images using postion abosolute and z index but cant get my images to scroll over each other.. :s any suggestions guys

```
 #lookbook img{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
 }

img#image1 {

z-index: 100;
 }

  img#image2 {

top: 0px;
z-index: 20;
  }
   img#image3 {

z-index: 30;
  }
  img#image4 {

z-index: 40;
 }
  img#image5 {

z-index: 50;
 }
 img#image6 {

z-index: 60;
 }
 img#image7 {

z-index: 70;
  }
  img#image8 {

z-index: 80;
  }
  img#image9 {

z-index: 90;
  }
```

defo need some javascript in here to make the images fix when it reaches the top any help guys

manged to get this but doesnt seem to work any help any one lol

```
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).scroll( function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#lookbook img').offset().top)
        $('#lookbook img').addClass('fixed');
       else
        $('#lookbook img').removeClass('fixed');
      } );

   } );
```

Comment: Start at the beginning. Like [here](http://teamtreehouse.com/), [here](http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0), and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML).

Comment: Perhaps this answer can get you started : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488390/can-you-layer-pictures-on-top-of-each-other-on-a-webpage

Comment: thanks for the reply guys ill look into and get back to you.

Comment: manged to stack my images on top using absolute position and z index but cant seem to get them to scroll on top scroll over each other.. ive update my question

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to slide the images( vertical or horizontal), you can start by looking at [this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [this](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). The two links will help you move your images. You can then specify what goes over what by playing around with z-index, by referring [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: thanks for the reply yep knew it had something to do with z=index think i need a jquery statement if images scroll to top fix and then sort out the z index..

Comment: manged to stack my images on top using absolute position and z index but cant seem to get them to scroll on top scroll over each other.. ive update my question